# How to install system Flash player to Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flash-player

My Chrome Flash plugin is constantly crushing and even if it's not crashing it's super slow to load. I have tried to solve the problem and it seem that disabling chrome "pepflashplayer" flash player plugin and enabling the system one should solve my problem. But I see only one flash player in chrome plugins.
I have tried to install flash player several times, tried to install different versions, but still can't see any additional system flash player in chrome plugins settings ( chrome://plugins/ ) only the native chrome pepflashplayer.

[Plugins settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdEvZ.jpg)

Chrome V:  45.0.2454.101

Flash V:   19.0.0.185

Windows 10 64bit